# POST data to Google Sheet web app from AWS Lambda

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

**CURRENTLY**

I have a Google Sheets App Script 'web app'

**Script in Goolge Sheets**

```js
function doPost(e) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Hello!")

  return "Success!"
}
```

**Google Apps Script Web App Config:**

```
Execute as: Me // or as User. I've tried both.

Who has access: Anyone within MyOrganisation
```

---

I want to make a POST request to the above Web App from AWS Lambda.

**AWS Lambda .js:**

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");

const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(
    {spreadsheetId}
);
 
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
});

let token = doc["jwtClient"]["credentials"]["access_token"];

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    const options = {
      host: 'script.google.com',
      path: "/macros/s/{myscriptid}/exec",  //<-- my web app path!
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': "Bearer "+ token
      }
    };
    
    //create the request object with the callback with the result
    const req = HTTPS.request(options, (res) => {
      resolve(JSON.stringify(res.statusCode));
    });

    // handle the possible errors
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });
    
    //do the request
    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));

    //finish the request
    req.end();
  });

console.log("response:"+JSON.stringify(response))
```

**GCP Service Account**

- I have a GCP Service Account, with permission to Google Sheets API, and otherwise unrestricted access.
- This Service account has `EDIT` access to the Google Sheet with the `doPost(e)` script.

*Token Output:*

```js
"jwtClient": {
  "_events": {},
  "_eventsCount": 0,
  "transporter": {},
  "credentials": {
      "access_token": "somelongvalue...............", //<-- what I use
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expiry_date": 1661662492000,
      "refresh_token": "jwt-placeholder"
  },
  "certificateCache": {},
  "certificateExpiry": null,
  "certificateCacheFormat": "PEM",
  "refreshTokenPromises": {},
  "eagerRefreshThresholdMillis": 300000,
  "forceRefreshOnFailure": false,
  "email": "serviceaccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
  "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nsomelongvalue=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
  "subject": null,
  "gtoken": {
      "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nsomelongvalue=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "rawToken": {
          "access_token": "somelongvalue...............",
          "expires_in": 3599,
          "token_type": "Bearer"
      },
      "iss": "serviceaccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "sub": null,
      "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "expiresAt": 1661662492000
  }
}
```

**ISSUE**

Current response:

`response:"401"`

- I cannot find any Google documentation on how to setup the headers to authenticate a request (from my service account) to my organisation restricted web app.
- When the Web App is open to "Anyone" then it runs fine, but as soon as I restrict to `MyOrganisation`, I struggle to find a way to authenticate my POST request.

**HELP!**

How do I set up a POST request to my Google Sheets web app such that it can be protected by authentication? Right now, I'd be happy to find ANY means to authenticate this request (not necessarily a service account) that doesn't leave it completed open to public.

**Should I use this hack?**

One idea I had was to put a "secret" into my lambda function, and then make the web app public. The web app would check the secret, if if matched, would execute the function.

Comment: @Rubén, how much time and what documentation? I have spent hours on it, and clearly am either reading the wrong documentation or still not getting it. Do you have a link for me that solves the above problem? I'm not coming here without hours of trying behind me.

Comment: @Rubén, unfortunately I didn't get help from that link. It's another Stackoverflow post with the same problem as me, an answer with 0 upvotes, that all it has is mention of "Drive API documentation has a really good example" with a link to a page where I could not find this "really good example" mentioned. Spent 30mins on it with no solution.

Comment: @Rubén, I am capable of googling and finding docs that mention "service account" and "auth" and "tokens", but not able to find anything that suggests why my script may not be working e.g. is what I am trying to do impossible e.g. is it impossible for a service account to be authorized to call a doPost web app API? or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Not sure how Google auth works but any specific secrets can go into AWS Secrets Manager. In this case, SSM’s Parameter Store can probably work too. Does your code work locally? If not, then I would remove the AWS lambda tag as it would not be helpful to anyone who thinks the issue is being caused by the Lambda.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use a service account to make a POST request to a Google Apps Script web application but also it's possible to make it directly to Google Sheets API. If you are the only one working in your project, I think that it's a lot better to use the Sheets API, first because your project will be less complex and second because Google Apps Script services are very slow compared to the corresponding REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In order to access Web Apps using the access token with a script, the scopes of Drive API are required to be included. Those are `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, and so on. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- When I saw your showing script, it seems that the access token is retrieved using `google-spreadsheet`. When I saw the script of `google-spreadsheet`, it seems that this uses only the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/456ce2563db894ed9db541c26dc415f7bfde01b6/lib/GoogleSpreadsheet.js)

From this situation, I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to this. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification? In this modification, the access token is retrieved by googleapis for Node.js from the service account. [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Hello!")
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success!"); // Modified
}
```

- When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.
- You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

##### Node.js side:

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const HTTPS = require("https");

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  "###", // Please set client_email here.
  null,
  "###", // Please set private_key here. When you set private_key of service account, please include \n.
  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],
  null
);

function req(token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const data = { key1: "value1" }; // Please set your value.

    const options = {
      host: "script.google.com",
      path: "/macros/s/{myscriptid}/exec",  //<-- my web app path!
      method: "POST",
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + token},
    };
    const req = HTTPS.request(options, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode == 302) {
        HTTPS.get(res.headers.location, (res) => {
          if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            res.setEncoding("utf8");
            res.on("data", (r) => resolve(r));
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        res.on("data", (r) => resolve(r));
      }
    });
    req.on("error", (e) => reject(e.message));
    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    req.end();
  });
}

auth.getAccessToken().then(({ token }) => {
  req(token).then((e) => console.log(e)).catch((e) => console.log(e));
});
```

- When this script is run, when the Web Apps is correctly deployed, the script of Web Apps is run and `Success!` is returned.

#### Note:

- If this modified script was not useful for your Web Apps setting, please test as follows.

  - Please confirm whether your service account can access to the Spreadsheet again.
  - Please share the email address of the service account on the Spreadsheet. From your showing Google Apps Script, I thought that your Google Apps Script is the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet.
  - Please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps.

    - When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.
    - You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- When you set `private_key` of service account, please include `\n`.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

### Added:

When you will directly put the value to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API with `google-spreadsheet` module, you can also use the following script.

```js
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");

const sample = async () => {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("###"); // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
  });

  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle["Sheet1"];
  await sheet.loadCells("A1");
  sheet.getCell(0, 0).value = "Hello!";
  await sheet.saveUpdatedCells();
};

sample();
```

- In this case, your service account is required to be able to access to the Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Great answer as always Tanaike. I think that the core issue isn't the Google Apps Script web app but the call done using the service account OAuth credentials and scopes. Considering this, I think that it might be better to get the spreadsheet data by using the Google Sheets API, avoiding the use of the Apps Script web app. Do you consider that this might help to improve the overall reliability and performance of the OP's project?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately getting a new error now "The domain policies associated with the user are invalid or non existent." Note: web app is set for "User Accessing the web app" and "Anyone with a Google Account".

I am also a little concerned about the size of the `googleapis` package versus `google-spreadsheet`, both which authenticate but the latter is more bloated and required me to increase my aws lambda memory from 128MB to 256MB

Comment: Also, occasionally the result is "Authorization needed" or "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established". Not once have I successfully received the result "Success!"

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your comment and your always support. When I saw OP's question for the first time, I thought that OP might be required to access Spreadsheet using Web Apps because of the permission of the organization. But, from your comment, I thought that when multiple approaches are proposed, those might be useful. So, I added one more sample script for put a value to Spreadsheet using `google-spreadsheet` module with the service account.

Comment: @Wronski Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. First, my proposed script supposes that your service account can access to your Web Apps. Please be careful about this. About `The domain policies associated with the user are invalid or non existent.`, in this case, I'm worried that your service account have the permission for accessing your Web Apps. Please confirm it again.

Comment: @Wronski And, about `I am also a little concerned about the size of the googleapis package versus google-spreadsheet, both which authenticate but the latter is more bloated and required me to increase my aws lambda memory from 128MB to 256MB`, in this case, how about retrieving the access token without using googleapis for Node.js?

Comment: @Wronski About `Also, occasionally the result is "Authorization needed" or "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established". Not once have I successfully received the result "Success!"`, I apologize for this. In this case, please confirm whether your service account can access to Web Apps again. When your service account cannot access Web Apps, even when the access token is used, it cannot access. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Wronski By the way, as I mentioned in my answer when you share your Spreadsheet with the email of the service account, does the same error occur? Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand it. This is due to my poor English skill. About this, I have to apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Wronski And, from Rubén's suggestion, I added a sample script for directly putting a value to Spreadsheet using `google-spreadsheet` module with the service account. Could you please test it? When that is the same issue related to the authorization, it is considered that the reason for your issue is due to the permission. So, please confirm it again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for all your assistance and detailed solution. I appreciate all the help so far! (1) Yes, I am able to get the `google-spreadsheet` working, and (2) No, I am still unable to get the `doPost` script working. Response = `Authorization needed`. Note: web app is set for "User Accessing the web app" and "Anyone with a Google Account". Where else should I provide the Authorization?

Comment: @Tanaike, More info: (1) when I use `Execute as Me, Access = Organisation` then error = `The domain policies associated with the user are invalid or non existent.`, (2) when I use `Execute as User, Access = Anyone` then error = `Authorization needed`. But either way, `google-spreadsheet` API works just fine.

Comment: @Wronski Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. From `(1) Yes, I am able to get the google-spreadsheet working`, I understood that you could put a value to the Spreadsheet using google-spreadsheet module. In your goal, you are required to put a value to Spreadsheet using Web Apps?

Comment: @Wronski About `(2) No, I am still unable to get the doPost script working. Response = Authorization needed. Note: web app is set for "User Accessing the web app" and "Anyone with a Google Account". Where else should I provide the Authorization?`, in this case, it is required to confirm whether your service account can be accessed to your Web Apps. In this case, it might be required to ask to the administrator.

Comment: @Wronski And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, I couldn't understand the result of the case that your Spreadsheet with the container-bound script of Web Apps is shared with the email of the service account.

Comment: @Tanaike, yes, Spreadsheet (with script and web app) is shared with Service Account

Comment: @Wronski Thank you for replying. In your current situation, the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of the service account. And, you can put a value to Spreadsheet using google-spreadsheet with the service account. And, under this condition, when your Web Apps is accessed with the access token from the service account, an error related to the authorization occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike (1) the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of the service account - CORRECT, (2) you can put a value to Spreadsheet using google-spreadsheet with the service account - CORRECT, (3) when your Web Apps is accessed with the access token from the service account, an error related to the authorization occurs - CORRECT.

Comment: @Wronski Thank you for replying. From your reply, in that case, I would like to recommend asking whether, in your situation, the service account can access Web Apps with your current setting to the administrator of your organization. Because when I tested my proposed script, no error related to the authorization occurs and `Success!` is returned. So, I thought that when the issue related to the permission is removed, my proposed script works.

Comment: @Wronski As another confirmation, in your situation, when the access token of your account is used instead of the service account, what result will you obtain? If your access token can be used, it is considered that the reason for your current issue is due to the permission of the service account. If your access token occurs with the same result as the service account, it is considered that the reason for your current issue is due to the access to Web Apps. How about this? By the way, when you test your access token, please include the scope of Drive API.

Comment: @Tanaike, were you able to get the proposed script working with a Service Account? The service account I'm using is `App Engine default service account` with Basic Editor permissions, and I tested with Basic Owner permissions (same as my account), and Authorization issue persists. If you were able to get "Success!" returned, please let me know (1) service account configuration in GCP, and (2) web app configuration.

Comment: Also @Tanaike, I found on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts "Warning: The Apps Script API does not work with service accounts." Would this apply in this situation? Which is why I'm asking if you were able to get your script working with a Service Account.

Comment: @Tanaike and Ruben, I don't believe "it's possible to use a service account to make a POST request to a Google Apps Script web application" https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763096?pli=1

Comment: @Wronski About `were you able to get the proposed script working with a Service Account?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. So, I proposed this answer. By the way, who is the owner of the Spreadsheet in your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike, owner of Spreadsheet is "me" within a Google organisation. Service account has edit access to the Spreadsheet. If you were able to get the script working, please let me know (1) service account configuration in GCP, and (2) web app configuration.

Comment: @Wronski Thank you for replying. From your reply, I couldn't understand your situation of `As another confirmation, in your situation, when the access token of your account is used instead of the service account, what result will you obtain?`. By the way, about `Warning: The Apps Script API does not work with service accounts.`, the service account cannot run the Google Apps Script. This is the current specification. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Wronski About your additional 2 questions, the service account has the permissions for using Drive API and Sheets API. And, the setting of Web Apps is the same. By the way, when you change the setting of Web Apps to Anyone and the access token is not used, the script works? And, when you redeploy your Web Apps as new version and use new Web Apps URL, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike, when I use "Anyone", yes the script works. This is why I am asking when you got the script working, what settings did you use? i.e. `Execute As` and `Who has access`

Comment: @Wronski Thank you for replying. From your reply, I couldn't understand your situation of `As another confirmation, in your situation, when the access token of your account is used instead of the service account, what result will you obtain?`.