# Unable to run apps script function via node.js api - Requested entity was not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script

I want to run a google Apps Script function by calling it from a node.js service.

I have, enabled the apps script api in google cloud console, cerated an apps script project, shared it with my service account and created a function in Code.gs, and deployed the script as an API executable.

`Code.gs`:

```
function myFunction() {
   return "hello world";
}
```

When I try to call the function from my node.js service:

```
  const { script } = await Google.getInstance();
  const request = {
    scriptId: '<my_script_id>',
    resource: {
      function: 'myFunction'
    }
  };
  const response = await script.scripts.run(request);
```

I get the following error:

> The API call failed: GaxiosError: Requested entity was not found.

Googling suggests that this is a permission issue, that my service account doesn't have rights to the project. But to test if this is true I tried making another api call

```
const { script } = await Google.getInstance();
const response = await script.projects.get({
  scriptId: '<my_script_id>',
});
```

Which successfully return the metadata of my project:

```
{
  scriptId: '<my_script_id>',
  title: 'test 123',
  createTime: '2023-06-22T12:39:57.644Z',
  updateTime: '2023-06-22T12:55:56.291Z',
  creator: { photoUrl: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=h128' },
  lastModifyUser: { photoUrl: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=h128' }
}
```

This makes me believe that the scriptId is correct.

I also tried to un-share the project with my service account, and call the `script.projects.get` function again, and then I get another error `The caller does not have permission` - But I still get the same `Requested entity was not found` error why calling the `script.scripts.run` function.

When I instaciate the google client I only added `script.projects` to the scope:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: `${root}/config/google/credentials.json`,
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
  ]
});
```

This was suggested somewher in the documentation, and I haven't seens any instances of just: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scripts` for that matter. But I did try to add them for the sake of experimentation. But this creates a invalid auth object. Regardless of what request I try to make with an auth object contaning either, I am getting: `Invalid Credentials`

In [googles own documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#node.js) they are using an auth object with the scope only set to `drive` which I think must be a mistake. - there's also TODO comments in that documentation so I don't think it is usable.

Any idea what could be wrong ?
Thanks you!

Comment: I understand the script has been deployed, and I was wondering, have you tried to use the Deployment ID instead of the script ID?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run Google Apps Script using the service account with googleapis for Node.js.

### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, the execution method (Method: scripts.run) of Apps Script API cannot be used with the service account. The official document says as follows, [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute)

> Warning: The Apps Script API doesn't work with service accounts.

On the other hand, the method "Method: projects.get" except for "Method: scripts.run" can be used with the service account. I guessed that this is your current situation, and that is the reason for your current issue.

But, I think that there is a method for executing Google Apps Script using the service account with googleapis for Node.js, when Apps Script API is not used. In this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose using Web Apps. When the Web Apps is used, the usage is as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare Google Apps Script project.

As a sample script, please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor.

```js
const doGet = e => ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
const doPost = e => ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
```

#### 2. Share Google Apps Script project with service account.

Please share the above Google Apps Script project with the service account as a writer.

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen in [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone with Google account"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - By this setting, when you access your Web Apps, the access token is required to be used.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. When "The Web App requires you to authorize access to your data." is shown, please click "Authorize access" button. And, please authorize the scopes.
8. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. This URL is used for executing Google Apps Script.

**When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.** You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 4. Testing.

This sample script is modified [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73516397).

```js
const HTTPS = require("https");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const webAppsURL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  "###", // Please set client_email here.
  null,
  "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n###-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", // Please set private_key here,
  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],
  null
);

function req(token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = "sample value"; // This is a sample value.
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
    };
    const req = HTTPS.request(`${webAppsURL}?value=${data}`, options, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode == 302) {
        HTTPS.get(res.headers.location, (res) => {
          if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            res.setEncoding("utf8");
            res.on("data", (r) => resolve(r));
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        res.on("data", (r) => resolve(r));
      }
    });
    req.on("error", (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });
    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    req.end();
  });
}

auth.getAccessToken().then(({ token }) => {
  req(token).then((e) => console.log(e)).catch((e) => console.log(e));
});
```

- In this case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` can be used for accessing the Web Apps.
- When this script is run with `method: "POST"`, the following response is returned. In this case, the data can be included in the request body as the text type.

  ```
    {"postData":{"contents":"\"sample value\"","length":14,"name":"postData","type":""},"parameter":{"value":"sample value"},"contextPath":"","parameters":{"value":["sample value"]},"queryString":"value=sample%20value","contentLength":14}
  ```
- When this script is run with `method: "GET"`, the following response is returned. In the case of the GET method, only the query parameter is used. Please be careful about this.

  ```
    {"parameters":{"value":["sample value"]},"contentLength":-1,"parameter":{"value":"sample value"},"contextPath":"","queryString":"value=sample%20value"}
  ```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. You are absolutely right, I am trying to use a service account for this. I also noticed that the service accoutn wasn't visible under Apps Script in could console, but it was for docs, drive and sheets. (under credentials) - and there's no option to add it. I will give your workaround a try, it looks promising. I will get back as soon as I have tried it. Thanks

Comment: @Rasmus Puls Thank you for replying. When the approach of my answer was not useful, I apologize.